# What do these strings below the map names mean?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

In Dead by Daylight, I recently noticed that in the "Match Details" tab of the settings menu (accessible in the tally screen or if you press Escape during a match), there's a seemingly semi-random string of characters underneath the map name in the bottom right. Here's a collage of screenshots to show what I mean:

[image: Compiation of screenshots showing the map info section]

At first, I thought maybe this is simply the internal name of the map in the game files, but then I noticed that I'd get different strings for the same map (interestingly, while going through my screenshots, I noticed two separate occurences of the Silent Hill map that both had the string "B_Escape_01").

My next guess would be that these are some sort of seed for the random elements of map generation, such as how the structures spawn. But in that case, I would expect them to look a lot more random and not contain any real words (and also to not repeat at a noticeable frequency).

Does anybody know what they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Powerlord guessed in the comments, these strings appear to display the name of the tile you're currently within on the map, such as one of the maze tiles, a specific building, the exit gates etc. I was able to check what it said multiple times during the same game and verify this - even though many of the names are rather cryptic, they often correspond to what the tile actually is (such as "Foundry01" in the Ironworks of Misery map's main building). In the tally screen, what is displayed is most likely the last tile your character has visited before leaving the match.